# Specific Spatial Analyst tools failing while running extension using ArcGIS server

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, spatial-analyst, extensions

I am having having trouble running [ExtractValuesToPoints](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000002t000000.htm) on a remote server machine running ArcGIS Server (with ArcInfo and Spatial Analyst installed). It fails and throws a standard COM error. I have checked for any obvious issues with inputs/outputs and it runs just fine on several desktop machines running ArcGIS 10 Desktop (with ArcInfo and Spatial Analyst).

The interesting thing is the Spatial Analyst tool [Con](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000005000000.htm) works just fine in a previous geoprocessing step, which leads me to believe that it's not a licensing issue. I have even tested the inputs/outputs on the remote machine using the ArcGIS UI and it completes.

I apologize for the vagueness of the question, but I really can't seem to find any reason for one spatial analyst tool to work and another not (other than obvious issues with the data). I'd be happy to fill in any gaps if more information is needed. I guess I'm looking for a list of things I should be checking that I may have glanced over.

Comment: Have you confirmed they're all running the same service pack, using [PatchFinder.exe](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/patches-and-service-packs?fa=viewPatch&PID=17&MetaID=1774#idsp)?

Comment: Yes - all service packs are the same (latest).

Comment: So just to clarify, you have published a tool as a gp service.  The tool works in arcmap, but not when running as a gp service.  Is this correct?

Comment: The tool is published as an executable. It runs a series of geoprocessing steps, but also handles more system level things such as workspaces. It essentially takes in paths to GIS data and performs geoprocessing on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted this out. It turns out the server environment handles locked files from Arc differently than in a stand-alone desktop environment. Generally, you don't need to "release" locked files in the desktop environment in order to continue geoprocessing, but you need to Marshall them in the server environment. Lesson learned: best practice is to Marshall any files that can become locked.